# Invalid cross thread access exception in periodic task

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am trying to display my top tweet on the shell tile using periodic task agent. The tile has to get updated every 30 mins. Am using task parallel library for it to be continous. The problem is that am getting a "INVALID CROSS THREAD ACCESS" exception.

Here is my Schedule Task Agent code:

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    ShellToast popupMessage = new ShellToast()
    {
        Title = "My First Agent",
        Content = "Background Task Launched",
    };
    popupMessage.Show();

    UpdateTile().ContinueWith(x => NotifyComplete());
}

private Task<bool> UpdateTile()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    WebClient twitter = new WebClient();

    twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            var message2 = xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                                    .Select(x => x.Element("text").Value).FirstOrDefault();

            ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

            if (appTile != null)
            {
                StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
                {
                    BackContent = DateTime.Now.ToString() + message2.ToString()
                };

                appTile.Update(tileData);

                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            }
        }
    };

    twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=dnivra26"));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This is the line that is throwing the exception:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

//THIS IS THE CHANGE THAT I DID AND

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{

    ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

    if (appTile != null)
    {
        StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackContent = DateTime.Now.ToString() + message2.ToString()
        };

        appTile.Update(tileData);

        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
    else
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }

});
```

THIS IS THE LINE SHOWING EXCEPTION:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

Comment: Please check that Windows Mobile 7 doesn't exist: it's Windows Phone 7, which is a completely different OS and it doesn't use Compact Framework. Change your title and use more accurate tags! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since the work is being done on a background thread, you can't update the UI on the same thread. Instead, using `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` on sections where the UI is updated.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

    if (appTile != null)
    {
         StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
         {
              BackContent = DateTime.Now.ToString() + message2.ToString()
         };

         appTile.Update(tileData);

         tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
    else
    {
         tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: as you told i did use Dispatcher but still am getting that exception. this is the code is updated. Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {

    ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

    if (appTile != null)
    {
        StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackContent = DateTime.Now.ToString() + message2.ToString()
        };

        appTile.Update(tileData);

        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
    else
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }

});                Where am i going wrong??

Comment: It's a bit tricky to read code in the comments, could you please update your original post. Also, which line throws the error?

Comment: edited the question and posted the code in the last part. Please go through it and let me know where i am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the TPL.

Comment: "Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>"  is this line fine or you got to use some other object to access Dispatcher.BeginInvoke??